# How do I set the credentials of a a windows service log on?

Tags: c#, windows-services

How do I programmatically set the "Log On" credentials for an arbitrary Windows service using c# (wmi/interop is fine)?

Note, my program is running as an administrator and I need the change to persist (for all subsequent service restarts)

Ideally the method has the following sig:

```
void SetWindowsServiceCreds(string serviceName, string username, string password) 
{
   // TODO write me
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ChangeServiceConfig(IntPtr hService, UInt32 nServiceType, UInt32 nStartType, UInt32 nErrorControl, String lpBinaryPathName, String lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, String lpDependencies, String lpServiceStartName, String lpPassword, String lpDisplayName);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(
     string machineName,
     string databaseName,
     uint dwAccess);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Boolean QueryServiceConfig(IntPtr hService, IntPtr intPtrQueryConfig, UInt32 cbBufSize, out UInt32 pcbBytesNeeded);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG
{
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwServiceType;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwStartType;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwErrorControl;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpBinaryPathName;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpLoadOrderGroup;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwTagID;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpDependencies;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpServiceStartName;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpDisplayName;
};

private const uint SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = 0x000F003F;
private const uint SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x00001;
private const uint SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x00002;
private const uint SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = 0xffffffff;
private const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;

public static void SetWindowsServiceCreds(string serviceName, string username, string password)
{
    IntPtr hManager = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hService = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        hManager = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
        if (hManager == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ThrowWin32Exception();
        }
        hService = OpenService(hManager, serviceName, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG | SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);
        if (hService == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ThrowWin32Exception();
        }

        if (!ChangeServiceConfig(hService, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, null, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, username, password, null))
        {
            ThrowWin32Exception();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hService != IntPtr.Zero) CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        if (hManager != IntPtr.Zero) CloseServiceHandle(hManager);
    }
}

private static void ThrowWin32Exception()
{
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Win32Exception e = new Win32Exception(error);
    throw e;            
}
```

Comment: I chose this, cause it involves less dependencies and potentially provides richer error messages

Comment: Seems to work for me. I had to specify domain as part of the username string.

Answer (score 6):

This works as well:

```
void SetWindowsServiceCreds(string serviceName, string username, string password)
{
    string objPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName);
    using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath)))
    {
        object[] wmiParams = new object[10];

        wmiParams[6] = username;
        wmiParams[7] = password;
        service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to change the credentials to any built-in accounts (blank password). The invoke call throws an InvalidOperationException with the message "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.". This always happens even if the service is in a stopped state.