# Backup SQL Server database through C# other than Local System (from SQL Service)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-backups

I followed a quick guide to get a SQL Server database backed up from .Net (http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/2134/access-denied-during-database-backup). In short, updated SQL Service (Service) > Properties > Log On tab > Built-in account to `Local Service`.

I was wondering how I could avoid changing through Windows directly and specify some type of authentication in my code? Say I don't have access to the Service (via RDP, etc).

My code is as follows:

```
public void BackupDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        Backup sqlBackup = new Backup
        {
            Action = BackupActionType.Database,
            BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
            BackupSetName = "Archive"
        };

        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString
        };

        DatabaseName = (new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connection.ConnectionString)).InitialCatalog;
        FileName = DatabaseName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss") + ".bak";

        AbsolutePath = DestinationPath + FileName;

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(AbsolutePath, DeviceType.File);

        sqlBackup.Database = DatabaseName;

        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db = sqlServer.Databases[DatabaseName];

        sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
        sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
        sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

        sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

        sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
        sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

        sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

        sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);

        Success = true;
        Result = string.Format("<i>{0}</i> was successfully backed up to the following location: <i>{1}</i>", FileName, DestinationPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogHelper.AddExceptionLog("Helper.DatabaseHelper.BackupDatabase", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());

        Success = false;
        Result = string.Format("{0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: "I was wondering how I could avoid changing through Windows directly and specify some type of authentication in my code?" - I don't believe you can. In order to use SMO to create a backup, SMO talks to the SQL server service and the SQL server service has to be able to access the backup target folder structure.

Comment: you could maybe programmatically add/change credentials of the SQL server service, but I wouldn't recommend!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481598/how-do-i-set-the-a-windows-service-log-on-credentials