# Modifying path to executable of windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to write console application to change path to executable of windows service. More exactly it should take service name as argument then change service path to executable to given.
Unfortunately I cannot find any information how to achieve that, maybe someone with more experience could give any advice?

I found some interesting info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx but it also didn't help me.

Comment: You can use `sc config...` for this

Comment: Yes, I know it. But this fragment of code will be used in totally different place. First step for me is to write simple console application responsible for that.

Comment: This project probably has a lot of the pieces you'd need: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6164/A-ServiceInstaller-Extension-That-Enables-Recovery

Answer (score 1):

If you can't just call `sc.exe` to do it, you can use the interop code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4481667/909199) and add as follows:

```
public static void SetWindowsServicePath(string serviceName, string binPath)
{
    IntPtr hManager = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hService = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        hManager = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
        if (hManager == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ThrowWin32Exception();
        }
        hService = OpenService(hManager, serviceName, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG | SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);
        if (hService == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ThrowWin32Exception();
        }

        if (!ChangeServiceConfig(hService, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, binPath, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null, null))
        {
            ThrowWin32Exception();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hService != IntPtr.Zero) CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        if (hManager != IntPtr.Zero) CloseServiceHandle(hManager);
    }
}
```

As per `sc.exe` this code needs admin rights in order to open the SCM.