# How to set the logon details for a windows service which is installed via c# AssemblyInstaller call?

Tags: c#, windows, serialization, service, installation

I've searched long and hard for a solution to this, unfortunately nothing I've tried so far has worked.

**Question**: how do I set the logon credentials for the service this function is installing? At the moment it defaults to `localsystemaccount`.

When I try to add in an event handler to set the account and password for logon as per the example seen here:

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0xf9962fd5be4a761736a9d350fdd72135dd0954853d267eca8ccbd9349e15f467&fullName=VirtualBoxService/ElevatedService.cs&project=shabbirh/virtualboxservice

I get an error:

> Type 'System.Configuration.Install.InstallerCollection' in assembly 'System.Configuration.Install, version 4.0.0.0,.... .... is not marked as serializable"

```
 private bool TryInstallWindowsService(WindowsService WinService)
    {
        IDictionary mySavedState = new Hashtable();

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");


        // Create an object of the 'AssemblyInstaller' class.
        using (AssemblyInstaller Installer = domain.CreateInstance(typeof(AssemblyInstaller).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof(AssemblyInstaller).FullName, false, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.ExactBinding,
            null, new Object[] { WinService.DefaultPath, new String[] { } }, null, null, null).Unwrap() as AssemblyInstaller)
        {


            Installer.UseNewContext = true;

            //The below line causes an error to be thrown "Type 'System.Configuration.Install.InstallerCollection' in assembly 'System.Configuration.Install, version 4.0.0.0,....
            //.... is not marked as serializable"

            //Installer.BeforeInstall += new InstallEventHandler(installer_BeforeInstall);

            try
            {
                // Install the 'MyAssembly' assembly.
                myAssemblyInstaller.Install(mySavedState);

                // Commit the 'MyAssembly' assembly.
                myAssemblyInstaller.Commit(mySavedState);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                myAssemblyInstaller.Rollback(mySavedState);

                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                myAssemblyInstaller.Dispose();
            }
        }

        AppDomain.Unload(domain);

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: If anyone else is stuck with a similar scenario, change tack and set the credentials after the service is installed (adapt the answer at the bottom to suit your needs, works well):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481598/how-do-i-set-the-a-windows-service-log-on-credentials